# .NET MVC Controller not loading view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been asked to work on already existing code for a .NET MVC Application, and am required to add a new page. I have done this, but am having issues.

The application has a common layout defined in `_Layout.cshtml` page (I need to use the same layout for my new page). The path is present in `Viewstart.cshtml` page.

This is how an existing page works:
The controller has this code:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    TransactionHistoryViewModel model = new TransactionHistoryViewModel();
    model.SearchType = "TransactionHistory";
    return View(model);
}
```

When the code is run, immediately after executing the above lines, it goes on to the `_ViewStart.cstml` file and executes the following:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But when I try to use the same logic for the controller I have created (I have already set up the models):

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    TransportPlannerViewModel model = new TransportPlannerViewModel();
    model.SearchType = "TransportPlanner";
    return View(model);
}
```

the code stops executing after the above block, and does not move on to the `_ViewStart` file (I figured this out using breakpoints).

I am required by my employers to maintain consistency with the existing code, so I have tried to stick to the original coding style. Could this be an issue with wrong  model mapping or setup?

Comment: do you get any error, check routing code

Comment: seems like path issue here: ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml. check the path is correct or not.

Comment: Show the code in your View. Maybe you are performing some logic checking in there that is failing, or something is null etc...

Comment: Show the full controller/view/model source codes, and any errors that you have caught in Global.asax when  calling the action method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2x `public ViewResult Index()` in the same controller, it is not going to work, you will confuse the application about which method signature to choose, because they are identical.

You should have your **TransportPlannerViewModel** code in a seperate controller. and this should be pointing to a different View Folder associated with that controller.

Ie. If the controller for the first code block is **TransactionHistory**, then it will be looking for a view under ***Views\TransactionHistory\Index.cshtml***.

By default it uses the pattern Views\ControllerName\ActionName (methodName) to look for the view.

So to get it to work for your other method, if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should have a **TransportPlanner** Controller, then it will look for your view under ***Views\TransportPlanner\Index.cshtml***.

Please clarify if this is not what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No, I have two separate controllers - TransportPlannerController and TransactionHistoryController(this was already present when they handed over the code to me, and it works fine).

Comment: Does the view that is not working also have a reference to the layout file? ie. -> @{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Yes it does. I have replicated it exactly to the one that is working. Only difference is, I have tried to pull the data from a different table for the view I created  (which obviously meant I had to create new models accordingly, with properties corresponding to the other tables's columns). I am unable to post the code for the view right now because I got off work.

Comment: Ok would need to have  a look at the view to understand more, but I would suggest testing any code in the view (if you have any server side code in it) separately to see if its failing, if it is, that's why its not loading the view. (ie. extract out any logic / data retrieval code to a unit test)

Comment: Do you have both the index.cshtml placed at proper locations in the project? What do you see in the UI when you browse transportplanner/index ?

Comment: I did initially try using this view with existing models and data, and it worked fine. But when I changed them to use the models I created, it stopped working. I will post the view from work tomorrow. 

On a different note, is there a way to debug this? I tried using Firebug on Firefox (it always helps me), but did not see any errors under 'console'.

Comment: My employers have agreed to get me in touch with the original developer of the application, by hirinh him as an email/phone based consultant. Hopefully he will be able to educate me about it's design.

Thanks for the response!